# Getting Instant Preview to work with Unity & Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore, google-vr

Is there a specific trick to getting Instant Preview to work consistently and reliably with Unity and Android? (*)

I've connected the phone via USB, and also connected it using ADB-over-Wifi. I have a second phone running Google's Daydream Controller emulator app available... but (ironically?) it actually WASN'T available or in use on the few occasions when I got instant preview to work.

I got Instant Preview to work two or three times in "use phone for camera & motion sensors" mode, and I'd SWEAR that at least once I got it to (briefly) work in "render video on PC & stream it to phone" mode... but it was always by complete accident that I could never replicate or identify what it was that I actually did that caused it to suddenly start to work.

What I'm looking for at this point is some specific, concrete checklist of things to do in order that should, at least theoretically, result in a buildable Unity Android VR app where instant preview works predictably and reliably. Ideally, a checklist that involves a Nexus 6P (or at least, some other phone that's not officially Daydream-blessed, but nevertheless known to be capable of being coaxed into pretending it is for at least a few minutes until it overheats).

Or... alternatively... a downloadable Unity project somewhere with a "known good" configuration that someone can confirm works consistently with Instant Preview and a Nexus 6P, so I could at least pick it apart and figure out how ITS configuration deviates from the things I've tried up to this point.

---

(*) Unity 2018.2.13f1, GoogleVRForUnity_1.170.0.unitypackage, arcore-unity-sdk-v1.2.0.unitypackage, Nexus 6P w/Android 8.1, Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know after working with InstantPreview, **there is no "stable way to build".**

But if my answer on this question ([Running google-vr unity daydream app on google pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509873/running-google-vr-unity-daydream-app-on-google-pixel/49449883#49449883)) do not help you, and after one build your instant preivew do not work, you can also try to:

1. Close Unity and Reopen
2. Restart Phone
3. Re-install Instant Preview
4. Check if there is no previous build on the phone, if there is,
   delete it

Normally one of this 3 things allways works, depending on phone, in some phones needs a combination of more than one.